# Using ckeditor or tinymce

Tags: ckeditor, tinymce

I would like to build SaaS application (with free and not free tiers).
And I want to use one of the editors: ckeditor or tinymce.
I don't want to pay for it.

Can I legally use it?
Can I use it if I will make my client app (which using editor) - open source (MIT license)?

P.S.

CKeditor - GPL, LGPL, MPL

Tinymce - LGPL

Answer (score 1):

**From the CKEditor FAQ**:

> CKEditor is distributed under the GPL, LGPL and MPL Open Source licenses. >this triple copyleft licensing model is flexible and allows you to choose >the license that is best suited for your needs.
>
> The GPL grants the recipients of a computer program the rights of the free >software definition and uses copyleft to ensure the freedoms are preserved, >even when the work is changed or added to.
>
> The LGPL places copyleft restrictions on the program governed under it but >does not apply these restrictions to other software that merely link with >the program. The main difference between the GPL and the LGPL is that the >latter allows the work to be linked with a non-(L)GPLed program, regardless >of whether it is free software or proprietary software.
>
> The MPL allows covered source code to be mixed with other files under a >different, even proprietary license. However, code files licensed under the >MPL must remain under the MPL and be freely available in source form.

**From the Tinymce FAQ**:

> Are there any restrictions to using TinyMCE in my commercial
> application?
>
> Yes, there are restrictions including the following. All
> copyright notices must be intact as Moxiecode Systems are the
> copyright owners of the source code. You cannot use the source code in
> your applications without complying with the LGPL. According to the
> provisions of the LGPL, any modifications or add-ons you make to the
> source have to be released for the community's benefit. We recommend
> that you always contribute your changes back to the TinyMCE community,
> regardless of the situation. If you start to make a lot of revenue
> from using TinyMCE, please remember the time and dedication that has
> been put into this by other developers, respect this and give credit
> to those who deserve it.

As long as you don't mess with the source code you are fine to use it for your use case (own tinymce plugins are no problem regarding this license).
If i were you i'd would go for Tinymce.

Comment: Thank you for information. The problem is that this text hard to translate into allowed/not allowed.

I still didn't get the point about the preference of Tinymce if CKEditor has more licenses and LGPL included as well.

Comment: i am not stating that tinymce is superior licensewise (CKeditor got some additional licenses and thus more options) but i would go with tinymce from a technical view